# Triangulate over a manifold using CGAL

Tags: c++, math, triangulation, cgal

In my problem I want to triangulate (using CGAL dD Triangulation package) points on R^3 x S, where S is a mono-dimensional compact manifold.
But in the documentation that I've read the triangulation that CGAL performs is only on a n-dimensional Euclidean space.

At this point i need some help, since I'm not a big CGAL expert and I don't know even if this thing is possible or not (and if it's possible how to do it).

Thank in advance!

Comment: "mono-dimensional compact manifold": you mean a circle?

Comment: I don't think it is possible directly. There are functions in CGAL to compute periodic triangulations in 2d and 3d, but nothing for half-periodic (but I believe there are plans) and nothing in higher dimensions.

Comment: I believe the easiest is to "embed" your circle in R, actually several (3?) translated copies of it, triangulate that, and fix the result. That's not far from what the periodic triangulation packages do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am a CGAL developer, but I do not know well the dD triangulation package.)

I think that you cannot do a computation over R^3 x S using CGAL. If S is a embedable in R, I suggest you do the computation in R^4.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I'm doing now, but embedding S in R raise some duplication problems on the boundaries that are tricky to mange, so I'm looking for a cleaner solution.